# Google Drive and Translation Script

Tags: html, google-apps-script, google-drive-api, rss

I am using this script, but each time it fetches the RSS it creates a new HTML file.

I would like it to just rewrite the previous file instead of creating a new one and fetch only once a day. After that once i share the [file](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1NEVHYvV8ZI73z9KJum1f0AP4voHQnNkt/view?usp=sharing) is not validated in [RSS Validator](https://validator.w3.org/feed/) if there is any way to fix this changing mime or any other option. Any help with this would be appreciated.

```
function doGet() {

  var fromLang = "en";    
  var toLang   = "es";    
  var rssFeed  = "http://xkcd.com/rss.xml";  

  var feed = parseRSS(rssFeed, fromLang, toLang);   
  DriveApp.createFile("rssTest", feed, MimeType.HTML);
  return ContentService.createTextOutput(feed)
           .setMimeType(ContentService.MimeType.RSS);    
}

function parseRSS(feed, fromLang, toLang) {

  var id = Utilities.base64Encode(feed + fromLang + toLang);

  // Cache the RSS feeds for an hour
  var cache = CacheService.getPublicCache();
  var rss   = cache.get(id);

  if (rss != null) {
    return rss;
  }

  var item, date, title, link, desc, guid; 

  var txt = UrlFetchApp.fetch(feed).getContentText();
  var doc = Xml.parse(txt, false);  

  title = doc.getElement().getElement("channel").getElement("title").getText();

  // The RSS Feed is translated using Google Translate
  rss = '<rss version="2.0">';
  rss += "<channel><title>";
  rss += LanguageApp.translate(title, fromLang, toLang);
  rss += " (" + title + ")</title>";

  var items = doc.getElement().getElement("channel").getElements("item");   

  // Parsing single items in the RSS Feed
  for (var i in items) {

    try {

      item  = items[i];

      title = item.getElement("title").getText();
      link  = item.getElement("link").getText();
      date  = item.getElement("pubDate").getText();
      desc  = item.getElement("description").getText();

      guid  = Utilities.base64Encode(link + fromLang + toLang);

      title = LanguageApp.translate(title, fromLang, toLang);
      desc  = LanguageApp.translate(desc,  fromLang, toLang, 
                                       {contentType: "html"});

      rss += "<item>";
      rss += "  <title>"   + title + "</title>";
      rss += "  <link>"    + link  + "</link>";
      rss += "  <pubDate>" + date  + "</pubDate>";
      rss += "  <guid>"    + guid  + "</guid>";
      rss += "  <description><![CDATA[" + desc + "]]></description>";
      rss += "</item>";

    } catch (e) {
      Logger.log(e);
    }
  }

  rss += "</channel></rss>";

  cache.put(id, rss, 3600);
  return rss;

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can change the content of a file by just calling the method [`setContent()`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/drive/file#setcontentcontent). And if you know the ID you can get the file through [`DriveApp.getFileById()`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/drive/drive-app#getFileById(String)).

So this part of your code:

```js
DriveApp.createFile("rssTest", feed, MimeType.HTML);
```

Can change to this:

```js
var file = DriveApp.getFileById("<your file ID>");
file.setContent(feed);
```

---

I've tried to validate this RSS in the [validator you sent](https://validator.w3.org/feed/).

There are some things that I needed to do in order to validate.

1. In the `guid` tag there is an error, basically, you [need to add](https://validator.w3.org/feed/docs/error/InvalidHttpGUID.html) isPermaLink="false".
2. After that remember that the `channel` elements needs  `description` element and `link` check it at [w3schools](https://www.w3schools.com/xml/xml_rss.asp).

Doing that made it a valid RSS for me. So you need to change your `parseRSS` to make it work.

```
function parseRSS(feed, fromLang, toLang) {

  var id = Utilities.base64Encode(feed + fromLang + toLang);

  // Cache the RSS feeds for an hour
  var cache = CacheService.getPublicCache();
  var rss   = cache.get(id);

  if (rss != null) {
    return rss;
  }

  var item, date, title, link, desc, guid; 

  var txt = UrlFetchApp.fetch(feed).getContentText();
  var doc = Xml.parse(txt, false);  

  title = doc.getElement().getElement("channel").getElement("title").getText();

  // The RSS Feed is translated using Google Translate
  rss = '<rss version="2.0">';
  rss += "<channel><title>";
  rss += LanguageApp.translate(title, fromLang, toLang);
  rss += " (" + title + ")</title>";
  rss += "<description>Description you need to fill</description>"; // Add this line
  rss += "<link>Link you need to fill</link>"; // Add this line 

  var items = doc.getElement().getElement("channel").getElements("item");   

  // Parsing single items in the RSS Feed
  for (var i in items) {

    try {

      item  = items[i];

      title = item.getElement("title").getText();
      link  = item.getElement("link").getText();
      date  = item.getElement("pubDate").getText();
      desc  = item.getElement("description").getText();

      guid  = Utilities.base64Encode(link + fromLang + toLang);

      title = LanguageApp.translate(title, fromLang, toLang);
      desc  = LanguageApp.translate(desc,  fromLang, toLang, 
                                       {contentType: "html"});

      rss += "<item>";
      rss += "  <title>"   + title + "</title>";
      rss += "  <link>"    + link  + "</link>";
      rss += "  <pubDate>" + date  + "</pubDate>";
      rss += "  <guid isPermaLink="false">"    + guid  + "</guid>"; // Modified this line
      rss += "  <description><![CDATA[" + desc + "]]></description>";
      rss += "</item>";

    } catch (e) {
      Logger.log(e);
    }
  }

  rss += "</channel></rss>";

  cache.put(id, rss, 3600);
  return rss;

}
```

Comment: Any ideas for the second part of the question ? This is the feed https://drive.google.com/file/d/1NEVHYvV8ZI73z9KJum1f0AP4voHQnNkt/view?usp=sharing and it is not validating

Comment: Sorry I did not understand this second part, could you try to clarify so I can give you a hand?

Comment: basically that file should be validated in rss validator but it gives me this error Sorry
This feed does not validate.

line 1, column 0: XML parsing error: <unknown>:1:6: not well-formed (invalid token)
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1NEVHYvV8ZI73z9KJum1f0AP4voHQnNkt/view

Comment: I'v updated my answer to try to respond the RSS question you also had.

Comment: thanks for quick reply can you share the code how you got permalink=false and i see all elements on the code description / title / link / guid. I see all four of them.

Comment: There you have it look at the code where I have added comments. `Description` and `link` missing are from the `channel` node not the `item`'s one. And `guid` is an attribute.

Comment: rss += "  <guid isPermaLink=false>"    + guid  + "</guid>"; // Modified this line i removed the "false" or it gives me a error... this is the link parsed. https://drive.google.com/file/d/1NEVHYvV8ZI73z9KJum1f0AP4voHQnNkt/view which is still not validating.